# Adding values in columns if criteria is met (Tableau or Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tableau-api

I have the following data. I want to add the `TOT_INVC_WT` if there are duplicate containers in the same date.

So for e.g. right below I have the same container coming in on 7/30, I would like to add Column C where the weight should show 1827+657 and then delete the remaining duplicate rows.

Can I do it in Tableau or should I write a formula in Excel? Also how do I do that?

```
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   1827
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   657


CNTR_NO CNSLDT_PNT_SHP_DT   TOT_INVC_WT
UACU817605  7/30/2018   14204
MSCU354882  7/30/2018   12838
MEDU330814  7/30/2018   12775
FSCU418797  7/30/2018   12373
MSCU609617  7/30/2018   12237
MEDU330814  7/30/2018   3668
MSCU354882  7/30/2018   3668
MSCU609617  7/30/2018   2752
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   1827
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   657
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   657
MOAU064222  7/30/2018   612
TRHU181855  7/28/2018   75327
FCIU333003  7/28/2018   75327
APZU466496  7/28/2018   75327
ECMU210770  7/28/2018   75327
GESU667414  7/28/2018   75327
DVRU161307  7/28/2018   7740
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried already. See [ask].

Comment: Actually MOAU064222 appears 4 times in 7/30/2018 with 3 different values (1827, 657, 612) for the third column.

That being said, could you please provide the expected output in this scenario?

Comment: Hi Fabio the correct output will be 3096 (1827+657+612)

Answer (score 0):

Niprs, it's possible you can do this type of calc in Tableau Desktop, however, Tableau Prep is the correct tool for the job. If you haven't used Prep...this is a great educational use case. Download a trial [here](https://www.tableau.com/products/prep).

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to create cross-tab or charts in Tableau? or Are you just looking out to aggregate "TOT_INVC_WT" for duplicate "CNTR_NO"?

- If you are going to use this data to create cross-tab in tableau, tableau can automatically address this problem as shown in the picture
  [In Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as0X6.png)

Notice the blue circle, all your duplicate values are aggregated now

- If you want to aggregate this in excel then you can make use of pivot. Please refer
  [In Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs9Mw.png)

Hope I have answered your question!

Comment: Thank you Manoraj. What command did you use in tableau to get the unique container/ date combination?

Comment: Hello again Niprs! I have not used any calculated field to get to this. I would recommend you to replicate what is there under "In Tableau" for your understanding. Please do revert for further clarrifications if any! If I have answered your question, kindly upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do this in Tableau by using the LOD command Fixed. I would also like to add that my data had other fields apart from the fields I mentioned in the original question.It had the supplier code which I wanted to keep as is.

CNTR_NO          SHP_DT        SUPP_CD  TOT_INVC_WT

MSCU488063  27-Jul-18   E3321H0 19085

GLDU505576  27-Jul-18   C2410S0 16207

CRXU936347  27-Jul-18   W0331Z1 14950

TCLU285473  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 14248

GCNU130956  27-Jul-18   C2457N0 12860

MEDU296091  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 12782

GESU635995  27-Jul-18   X8358Z0 11584

FCIU497036  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 11214

INBU318009  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 8250

CAIU782939  27-Jul-18   W0331Z1 7475

CAIU782939  27-Jul-18   W0331Z1 7475

INBU318009  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 7304

TCLU554631  27-Jul-18   X8483B0 6540

FCIU497036  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 4595

CAIU259170  27-Jul-18   J7423T0 4215

MEDU296091  27-Jul-18   D9943G0 3342

GVCU405056  26-Jul-18   C0473V0 20837

CAXU811656  26-Jul-18   X8358Z0 17164

FSCU761214  26-Jul-18   D9943G0 15804

UACU414715  26-Jul-18   D9943G0 15073

MEDU759427  26-Jul-18   X8358Z0 14053

UACU810191  26-Jul-18   A4320T0 11769

TCLU493174  26-Jul-18   J0786X0 10192

KKFU801287  26-Jul-18   J0786X0 10192

GESU575065  26-Jul-18   J0786X0 9000

NTCLU989230 26-Jul-18   J0786X0 2548

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   D1137A0 2492

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   J0786X0 2460

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   G0191A0 64

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   J6507K0 48

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   F1811P0 44

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   C0521G0 7

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   U0078M0 3

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   X8490U0 1

TCLU989230  26-Jul-18   C0521G0 1

So I wanted to basically aggregate the total invoice weight keeping the shipping date and container number constant. However the supplier code should still show up.

I used the command called fixed in Tableau

{FIXED [Shp Dt],[Cntr No]: SUM([Tot Invc Wt])}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmwzu.png)

Look at the container number TCLU989230. So using this command in Tableau will add up all the weights but will repeat the lines for each supplier code. Is it possible to show just one line of invoice weight against same container / date combo but show all suppliers in the list?